# hide checkbox with jQuery, then check on server side if it's visible

Tags: jquery, vb.net, checkbox, visible

I have a few asp:CheckBox's on my page. 
I'm using jQuery to hide some of them (in various ways). 
Then, pressing a submit button brings me to the server-side, where i'm trying to determine (in various ways) if a specific checkBox is visible or not. 
But for some reason, in server-side all checkboxes are always visible!
how do I know which are hidden?

client code - either one of these:

```
$("#cb1").hide(); 
$("#cb1").css("display", "none"); 
$("#cb1").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

server code - either one of these:

```
myCheckBox.Visible               '- always True 
myCheckBox.Attributes("display") '- always "nothing" 
myCheckBox.Style("visibility")   '- always "nothing" 
myCheckBox.Style("visible")      '- always "nothing"
```

Comment: Don't know much about ASP, but are you sure you can check elements visiblity on the serverside after a form submit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submiting a form, right?
When you hide the checkbox, change it's value.
Then, server-side, check for that value.
I don't know if ASP can check for style attributes, but since it's a GET or POST, it can get the value.

Comment: yeah, I can do it, but I was hoping for a nicer way... (isn't it wierd that you can't tell if it's hidden or not??) thanks anyway.